# mysql_fetch_row returning every other row?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT `description`,`auction_id` FROM `auctions` WHERE `description` REGEXP  '(97(8|9))?[[:digit:]]{9}([[:digit:]]|X)'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo "$row[1]";
```

is there any reason why `echo "$row[1]";` returns every other row? the results i am getting is suggesting as such, I am trying to get every row

Comment: Does the query work properly in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: Well, the trivial conclusion (that doesn't blame others) is that "the code is *discarding* every other record" - so why? Pay attention to side-effects :D

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

To actually answer your question, **why** it is occurring

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); //this advances the internal data pointer by 1
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result); //this advances it by 1 more
```

Both are being executed in every iteration of your loop.
**You should use one, not both.**

Additionally, you shouldn't be using **mysql_*** functions in new code, as it is deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi as stated in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the fetch function two times and hence it appears to skip one row each time.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);    //This is not needed
echo "$row[1]";
}
```

Should be

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row[1];
}
```

Comment: this returns blank results for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the loop as:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

use:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $desc[] = $row['description'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the query work properly in phpmyadmin then either you can use

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['description'];
}
```

Or

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[1];
```

or

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['description']; //or
echo $row[1];
}
```